# How to validate/block shorten URL in string

Tags: javascript, php

I need to block/validate shorten URL in String. Below string contains shorten URL how can I block/validate this in string .

Hi #first_name# This is Mondi from Novato Cleaners. May I ask for a favor ? Our google https://bit.ly requires reviews. Could you provide one ?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this you need to follow these steps:

1- extract all urls from string.

2- request each urls and get there original location. very well explained here:

[How to get domain name from shortened URL with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115801/how-to-get-domain-name-from-shortened-url-with-javascript)

3- when you have `originalUrl`, just check if `url` != `originalUrl` then it is a shorten url.

Comment: was this a help ? @vignesh

Comment: var searchText = $("#text_message").val();
    var urls = searchText.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);
   
    if(urls != null && urls != ""){
        for (var i = 0, il = urls.length; i < il; i++) {
          if(urls[i] != null && urls[i] != ''){
                if(shorten_urls.includes(urls[i])==true){
                   //alert(urls[i]);
                   show_alert("error", "Doesn't support shorten url");
                   return false;
                }
          }
           
    }
    }

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find whether there is a URL in your string or not, if they're just replacing it what you need on that space

> /(https?://[^\s]+)/g

```js
var string = "Hi Vignesh This is Mondi from Novato Cleaners. May I ask for a favor ? Our google https://bit.ly requires reviews. Could you provide one ?Thank you";
var protomatch = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
var b = string.replace(protomatch, '');
console.log(b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yahiya. I need to block only shorten URL not all URL's what will be do for that?

Comment: @vignesh https://stackoverflow.com/a/8151236/7057771 check this out or just block some specific shorten URL